# Support for ES2018 in Cypress tests? (Object spread operator)

Tags: testing, cypress

I'm trying to run a Cypress test with ES2018 syntax:

```
describe("Cypress test", () => {

  const objA = { a: 1, b: 2 };
  const objB = { ...objA };

  ...
}
```

But when executed, I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError: /....../cypress/loginTest.js: Unexpected token (29:17)
  27 | 
  28 |   const objA = { a: 1, b: 2 };
> 29 |   const objB = { ...objA };
     |                  ^
```

I also tried to check browserify presets with following plugin:

```
// plugins.js
const browserify = require("@cypress/browserify-preprocessor");

module.exports = (on) => {
  const options = browserify.defaultOptions;

  // Check presets
  console.log(options.browserifyOptions.transform[1][1].presets);

  on("file:preprocessor", browserify(options));
};
```

and it seems to already have `babel-preset-env` set-up.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but here's what worked for me:

I've managed to pretty painlessly enable the new es features (incl. *spread operator*), just using the `cypress-webpack-preprocessor` plugin and the examples [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor)

More info can be found in this discussion: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/905 and in **cypress**' [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/preprocessors-api.html#Examples)

***Note***, that you also have to include the desired *babel presets* as `node` dependencies in your `package.json` file and install them!

I've also found this pre-processor: [cypress-babel-esx-preprocessor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-babel-esx-preprocessor), but never got to trying it, since the *webpacker solution* worked straight away.

Finally, you may also want to watch [this request](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2069) for updating Chrome version in **cypress**'s Electron, as it's supposed to enable **es-2018** just out of the box.